# HTTP Request Contains Uncouth Characters

Tags: http

I have a script sending data to a RESTful API. I'm troubleshooting an intermittent error and can't find any problems in syntax. However, looking at the return request reveals some funny business.

```
6914ðnicity=Hispanic%2FLatino
&discipline=director
&yearsTeaching=
&facultyType=Not+Applicable
°ree=Doctorate
```

Notice the first and last line start strangely. The first line should be `&Ethnicity` and the second line should be `&Degree`. In the script they are labeled simply "Ethnicity" and "Degree". Pretty straightforward so I have no idea how or why these characters are being returned. The other thing is that I'm not confident that this is related to the error I'm after since the exception apparently occurs at a separate line of code. The thing that makes me think it's related is that the API that's receiving the data DOES NOT accept Unicode characters such as `ð` and `°`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this call isn't originating from my server but rather a web service I don't control. Apparently I confused some output logs. Thanks~~